# Index time boosting is not working with boosting value in document level

Tags: time, solr, indexing, document

We are having 10 documents (all 10 documents with name_s="john" or name_s="john abraham") with boosting value 10.0 in doc level out of 100 documents.
DataImportHandler is used to index the documents in xml.
We gave omitNorms="false" in a field called "text" and having schema.xml configured as below.
Default query field is "text", when i use q=john, the 10 documents which are having boosting is not coming in first 10 results.

Could anyone help on this issue?

Comment: yes i tried, even with or without boost values in document there is no change in the score.

Comment: Score is not coming properly even after giving boost value in document and field level.
   Doc with id 'ABCDEF/L' is boosted and doc with id 'MA147LL/A' is not boosted, but both are returning same score -> 0.1942141.
   Could you please help me to find where I did a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.
I was importing the XML using DIH and in the data-config.xml I did not mention 
`<field column="$docBoost" xpath="/doc/@boost"/>` which was the root cause of the problem.